# Определить "полную" загрузку страницы

Tags: javascript, html, html5

**1**.Подскажите пожалуйста, вот к примеру загружаю я страницу, вижу, что загружен основной HTML, потому вижу, что загружены все скрипты. По сути это можно считать загрузкой HTML-страницы.

**2**.Но, после загрузки всех этих данных, начинают, как я понимаю отрабатываются js-скрипты браузером, ну к примеру начать подгружать данные для графика и его последующего рендеринга на странице.

И вот небольшая проблемка, мне нужно к примеру на графике нажать кнопку, однако на момент выполнения п.1 - я не знаю отобразился ли сам график или нет, то есть по простому - есть ли уже кнопка, которую можно нажать или нет.

Вот и вопрос, можно ли это как то определить ?

Comment: Скрипт графика не ваш? Вы хотите программно кликнуть?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да, хотелось бы программно кликнуть. Но похоже один способ я понял. Нужно посмотреть название класса элемента-кнопки, к примеру через DevTools Хрома. А потом по мере загрузки страницы - проверять появилось ли название этого класса в итоговом HTML.  Если появилось, то теоретически можно вызвать JS-код по типу: document.getElementsByClassName(...).click()